# aggregate values of a column upto that row for each row mysql

Tags: mysql, row, aggregate

I have a table with the following fields:

```
season, collection, product_key, units_sold
```

I want to add extra

```
cumulative_sold column(aggreate of previous rows values)
```

which should satisfy `order by season, collection,units_sold`

```
sample input
---------- 
ss,f1,1,3
ss,f1,2,4
ss,f1,3,4
ss,f2,1,1
ss,f2,5,1

expected output 
--------------
ss,f1,1,3,3 
ss,f1,2,4,7(3+4)
ss,f1,3,4,11(3+4+4)
ss,f2,1,1,1
ss,f2,5,1,2(1+1)
```

Comment: You just asked that question.

Comment: Plase format your question properly and add what you tried.

Comment: question correct only...it is challenging question...

Comment: i hope now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cumulative sum using a correlated subquery:

```
select season, collection, product_key, units_sold,
       (select sum(units_sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.season < t.season or
              t2.season = t.season and t2.collection < t.collection or
              t2.season = t.season and t2.collection = t.collection and t2.units_sold <= t.units_sold
       ) as cumsum            
from t;
```

This is standard SQL.  If you have a significant amount of data, you will want an index on `t(season, collection, units_sold)`.

EDIT:

If you want this only for a particular collection in a particular season, rather than an overall cumulative sum:

```
select season, collection, product_key, units_sold,
       (select sum(units_sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.season = t.season and t2.collection = t.collection and
              t2.units_sold <= t.units_sold
       ) as cumsum            
from t;
```

EDIT II:

This is a pretty standard type of SQL.  It would help if you would get the question correct.  To handle duplicates on `units_sold`:

```
select season, collection, product_key, units_sold,
       (select sum(units_sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.season = t.season and t2.collection = t.collection and
              (t2.units_sold < t.units_sold or
               t2.units_sold = t.units_sold and t2.product_key <= t.product_key
              )
       ) as cumsum            
from t;
```

Comment: 'AW11', 'Female Bags', '678', '1', '5'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '675', '1', '5'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '679', '1', '5'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '689', '1', '5'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '677', '1', '5'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '669', '2', '9'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '682', '2', '9'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '691', '3', '12'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '695', '4', '16'
'AW11', 'Female Bags', '683', '5', '26'

Comment: it is not working...look at my sample input and expected output...thanks for ur effort...

Comment: yours is not working if units_sold is not unique....i will update sample input and expected output...check it

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Oh, I missed your 100k. I wanted to vote that time... ;)